# Best practice for storing and later accessing JSON object in rails database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm creating a Ruby-on-rails where photos can be uploaded, analysed and tagged. We're using [Azure's Cognitive Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) which can e.g. return a list of tags associated with a given image.

An example of tags for one image in JSON format is:

```
{"tags":[
{"tag_name":"outdoor","tag_confidence":"99.87"},
{"tag_name":"clothing","tag_confidence":"99.56"},
{"tag_name":"person","tag_confidence":"99.55"},
{"tag_name":"human face","tag_confidence":"93.33"},
{"tag_name":"tree","tag_confidence":"93.17"},
{"tag_name":"smile","tag_confidence":"91.33"}}
```

Right now we're just storing this as a hash in the table, but later we'd like to be able to do filtering or queries, where we can e.g. get all images with the *person*-tag. How do I go about creating the model and the tables for this in the best way?

Comment: Postgres has a JSON data types https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

Comment: @Eyeslandic ah yes, thanks! That is what we're using. Is this ok for later doing queryies of all images with a specific tag on a large number of images?

Comment: With proper indexing I would think so yes, I'm not a database expert though. Have you read the part about GIN indexing, there is talk about performance there.

Comment: I'm not sure how well GIN indexing will work with an array of objects (documents) in a JSONB column. But I'm also not a database expert.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning on querying the data and it has a regular structure then you might be better served by using actual tables.

```
# rails g model tag name:string:uniq
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  validate_uniqueness_of :name
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :photos, through: :taggings
end

# rails g model tagging tag:belongs_to photo:belongs_to confidence:float
# add a unique index on tag_id and photo_id
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  validate_uniqueness_of :tag_id, scope: :photo_id
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :photo
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

```
class TaggingService
  def initialize(photo)
    @photo = photo
    @tag_data = get_it_somehow(photo)
  end

  def perform(photo)
    @tag_data.each do |raw|
      photo.taggings.create(
        confidence: raw["tag_confidence"],
        tag: Tag.find_or_create_by(name: raw["tag_name"])
      )
    end
  end

  def self.perform(photo)
    new(photo).perform
  end
end
```

You can then for example query for a photo with a given tag just by:

```
Photo.joins(:tags)
     .where(tags: { name: 'outdoor' })
```

Or a set of tags:

```
Photo.left_joins(:tags)
     .group(:id)
     .where(tags: { name: ['outdoor', 'clothing', 'tree'] })
     .having('COUNT(tags.*) >= 3')
```

Sure you can do this with a JSON column but the queries are going to be much more difficult to read and you lose all the advantages to having database normalization and having actual models to work with.

One example of this is if you for example want to display tags based on aggregates:

```
Tag.left_joins(:taggings)
   .order('COUNT(taggings.*)', 'AVG(taggings.confidence)')
```

If you used a JSONB column you would have to extract that from every row on the `photos` table with a nightmarish query.